# Creating a method to find a float pint number in a file

Tags: java, static-methods, nested-loops

I've created a method to search for the amount of float point numbers in an imported text file. The file itself has over 20 float point numbers but I keep getting 0 as the amount of float numbers in the text. The method is boolean and searches the text file character by character. The main method then uses the boolean value to count the number of floats

```
public static boolean isFloat(String token) {
    if(!(token).contains(".")) return false;
    if (token.startsWith("+") || token.startsWith("-")) {  
    for (int i = 0; i < token.length(); i++) {
            if (! Character.isDigit((token).charAt(i))) {
                if (!token.contains("."))
                    return false;
            }
        }   
    }

    return true;
}

Loop within main: 
while (checkFile.hasNext()) {
    words = checkFile.next();
    if (!notWord == isWord(words)) {
        word++;

    } else if (! notDigit == isInteger(digits)) {
        number++;
    } else if (!notFloat == isFloat(floatNum)) {
        decimalNum++;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're assuming all positive numbers start with a '+', whereas that's not usually the case...

Comment: Can you provide a sample input?

Comment: No I used an if statement to check for '+' or '-'

Comment: Sample input:  1234  Sam  Jones  Salesperson  45000.00  +.99  7000.00 10000.00
C  -1222  Kelly  Miller  Salesperson  48000.00  -.850  5000.00 4500.00

Comment: You'll find the numbers  +123.45 and -123.45, but not 123.45 since the '+' is implied and not written.

Comment: Why not just try `Float.parseFloat` and check for exceptions?

Comment: so should I add an extra '||' to the if statement token.startsWith(" ")

Comment: because I'm supposed to use loops to find the float point numbers but the loop in float point method isnt working correctly @Quirliom